# What does "take" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qVoLTp46nP8&t=2s

This is a scene from the movie "The Shining" by Stanley Kubrick.
As you can see in the video Wendy utters the following line after racing toward the maze with Danny.

```
                      WENDY
        Okay Danny, you win.  Let's **take**
        the rest of this walking, huh?
```

"**take**"
a. To undertake, make, or perform: *take a walk; take a decision.*(source: American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language)

Is this the correct definition?

Does it mean they will **undertake the rest of their excursion** by walking?

Comment: Seems to fit, you know that she she intends to walk for the remainder of the activity.  Any reason to think otherwise?

Comment: In your last question, you asked about Wendy coming up behind Danny (running). Now she has caught him, he suggests walking for the rest of their walk in the maze.

Comment: I know what it means from context but I would like to know exactly what the word means, so I can use it and understand it in different situations. Can you confirm that it means "undertake"?

Comment: @Michael Harvey  I know what it means from context but I would like to know exactly what the word means, so I can use it and understand it in different situations. Can you confirm that it means "undertake"? (sorry for such a late comment but I wrote it back when I posted and forgoted to @you)

Comment: 'Let's undertake the rest of this walking' is understandable and grammatical, but also formal and stiff, and is not something people would say in conversation.